# Regex.prototype.exec returns null on second iteration of the search

Tags: javascript, regex

## Use Case

I'd like to search a string for several matches. Each match is eventually linked to an object property in an object array. When a match is found, that match is replaced by another property within an object. The problem is the code will always return null on the second match.

### Test Case

This is the test case that I am using. To simplify the problem, I just replace all matches with the number 5, but note that the final code will be replacing the match with a variable value.

#### Test Code

Below is the code I'm using to test and debug the issue. The interesting thing is that if I change `var str = '5 + QUESTION_2'`, `QUESTION_2` is successfully replaced with 5. Essentially, the problem boils down to the second match always returning null even though it can be matched.

```
var re = /( |^)(QUESTION_1|QUESTION_2|QUESTION_3)( |$)/g;
var str = 'QUESTION_1 + QUESTION_2';
var rep = 5;

matches = re.exec(str);
var re2 = new RegExp("( |^)(" + matches[2] + ")( |$)", "g");
console.log(matches); // Returns a match on QUESTION_1
str = str.replace(re2, rep);
console.log(str); // Returns 5+ QUESTION_2

matches = re.exec(str);
console.log(matches); // Returns a match on NULL - doesn't find QUESTION_2
re2 = new RegExp("( |^)(" + matches[2] + ")( |$)", "g");
str = str.replace(re2, rep);
console.log(str); // Returns 5+ QUESTION_2
```

### Question

- Why is the second match always null?
- The [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/MrRampage/nN2nk/) is available here.

Comment: The selected answer correctly identifies the issue, however I believe that you should be doing what I suggest in mine rather than relying on multiple execs and tweaking the `lastIndex`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since you're using global flag in exec call regex engine remembers lastIndex which is is a read/write integer property of regular expressions that specifies the index at which to start the next match.

Place this to reset it:

```
re.lastIndex=0;
```

Just before next call to RegExp.exec

`re.lastIndex = 0` allows you to reset the search index to perform a second search starting from the beginning. Without it, the search begins at the index of the last match, which would yield `null` in this case.

Read this [Mozilla doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/lastIndex) for more info on this. As per this manual:

This property is set only if the regular expression used the "g" flag to indicate a global search.

Answer (score 2):

When calling exec on a global regex, it remembers where was the last match and starts the next one from there.

```
var rx = /a/g, matches = rx.exec('aa');
rx.lastIndex; //1
```

When you modify your input string, between `exec` calls, the `lastIndex` becomes desychronised.

While there's a few way to fix this, I would rather perform the replace in a single statement.

```
'QUESTION1 + QUESTION2 + QUESTION3'.replace(/QUESTION\d+/g, function ($1) { 
    return 'VALUE_FOR_' + $1; 
});

//"VALUE_FOR_QUESTION1 + VALUE_FOR_QUESTION2 + VALUE_FOR_QUESTION3"
```

Comment: Interesting solution. I'm going to have to play around with this. The use case is a bit more complex in the real code, but I think this could be leveraged and could simplify my production problem. In the production problem the replacements are also variable, I just used `QUESTION_?` to simplify it. However, for this particular test case, this is a much more elegant solution +1.

Comment: @mister_rampage You mean that what has to be replaced might vary based on the last match? If you explain your real problem perhaps I could help you to find a working solution.

Comment: Just wanted to let you know that your solution was gold. Much more elegant for than the original looping solution. Thanks a bunch for all your help. I wish I could accept both answers.

Comment: @mister_rampage I'm glad to hear this. Unfortunately that's not possible and you have to pick the one that better answers the question. Not only for you but also for others ;) I just want to say that setting back the `lastIndex` to `0` might work, but not in every case, since it will start matching again at the beginning of the string. Depending on your replacements, it could produce wierd behaviours.