# Regex in online test tool works well, but misses many matches when applied in application

Tags: javascript, regex

As the title says, my regex in the online tester works, but it is less effective (i.e. missing some matches) when I use it in my application.

I am working on an application to get quotes from wikiquotes and present them to a user. The regex for determining which blocks of HTML are potential candidates for containing a quote seems fairly reliable. The regex I am using for obtaining the name of the author is problematic. The `get_author` function contains the regex pattern that seems to be missing matches when run in the browser, even though it successfully matches when used with the online tool. [Here is my regex in the tester, with the regex pattern and the HTML string I am parsing.](https://regex101.com/r/6lJjys/1/).

Note: I am aware that my regex has some mistakes in what it matches/matching too many HTML blocks. That's not my issue here, I will work towards refining the regex once I understand where these discrepancies are coming from.

What is the cause of the issue here?

**CODE**

```
$(document).ready(function(){


    //Make a call to the war page as soon as the page is loaded and get the page HTML
    $.ajax({
      url: "https://en.wikiquote.org/w/api.php?",
      dataType: "json",
      data: {
        action: "parse",
        page: "War",
        origin: "*",
        format: "json",
      },
        method: "GET",
        success: function(return_data, status){
            html_return = return_data.parse.text["*"];
            quote_candidates = get_quote_candidates(html_return);
            authors = get_author(quote_candidates);     
        }
    }); 
});


function get_author(quote_candidates){
    authors = [];

    var re = /<ul>\n<li>[\w\W]*?<ul>\n<li>[\w\W]*?title="?(w:|wikipedia:)?([\u0041-\u005A\u0061-\u007A\u00AA\u00B5\u00BA\u00C0-\u00D6\u00D8-\u00F6\u00F8-\u02C1\u02C6-\u02D1\u02E0-\u02E4\u02EC\u02EE\u0370-\u0374\u0376\u0377\u037A-\u037D\u0386\u0388-\u038A\u038C\u038E-\u03A1\u03A3-\u03F5\u03F7-\u0481\u048A-\u0527\u0531-\u0556\u0559\u0561-\u0587\u05D0-\u05EA\u05F0-\u05F2\u0620-\u064A\u066E\u066F\u0671-\u06D3\u06D5\u06E5\u06E6\u06EE\u06EF\u06FA-\u06FC\u06FF\u0710\u0712-\u072F\u074D-\u07A5\u07B1\u07CA-\u07EA\u07F4\u07F5\u07FA\u0800-\u0815\u081A\u0824\u0828\u0840-\u0858\u08A0\u08A2-\u08AC\u0904-\u0939\u093D\u0950\u0958-\u0961\u0971-\u0977\u0979-\u097F\u0985-\u098C\u098F\u0990\u0993-\u09A8\u09AA-\u09B0\u09B2\u09B6-\u09B9\u09BD\u09CE\u09DC\u09DD\u09DF-\u09E1\u09F0\u09F1\u0A05-\u0A0A\u0A0F\u0A10\u0A13-\u0A28\u0A2A-\u0A30\u0A32\u0A33\u0A35\u0A36\u0A38\u0A39\u0A59-\u0A5C\u0A5E\u0A72-\u0A74\u0A85-\u0A8D\u0A8F-\u0A91\u0A93-\u0AA8\u0AAA-\u0AB0\u0AB2\u0AB3\u0AB5-\u0AB9\u0ABD\u0AD0\u0AE0\u0AE1\u0B05-\u0B0C\u0B0F\u0B10\u0B13-\u0B28\u0B2A-\u0B30\u0B32\u0B33\u0B35-\u0B39\u0B3D\u0B5C\u0B5D\u0B5F-\u0B61\u0B71\u0B83\u0B85-\u0B8A\u0B8E-\u0B90\u0B92-\u0B95\u0B99\u0B9A\u0B9C\u0B9E\u0B9F\u0BA3\u0BA4\u0BA8-\u0BAA\u0BAE-\u0BB9\u0BD0\u0C05-\u0C0C\u0C0E-\u0C10\u0C12-\u0C28\u0C2A-\u0C33\u0C35-\u0C39\u0C3D\u0C58\u0C59\u0C60\u0C61\u0C85-\u0C8C\u0C8E-\u0C90\u0C92-\u0CA8\u0CAA-\u0CB3\u0CB5-\u0CB9\u0CBD\u0CDE\u0CE0\u0CE1\u0CF1\u0CF2\u0D05-\u0D0C\u0D0E-\u0D10\u0D12-\u0D3A\u0D3D\u0D4E\u0D60\u0D61\u0D7A-\u0D7F\u0D85-\u0D96\u0D9A-\u0DB1\u0DB3-\u0DBB\u0DBD\u0DC0-\u0DC6\u0E01-\u0E30\u0E32\u0E33\u0E40-\u0E46\u0E81\u0E82\u0E84\u0E87\u0E88\u0E8A\u0E8D\u0E94-\u0E97\u0E99-\u0E9F\u0EA1-\u0EA3\u0EA5\u0EA7\u0EAA\u0EAB\u0EAD-\u0EB0\u0EB2\u0EB3\u0EBD\u0EC0-\u0EC4\u0EC6\u0EDC-\u0EDF\u0F00\u0F40-\u0F47\u0F49-\u0F6C\u0F88-\u0F8C\u1000-\u102A\u103F\u1050-\u1055\u105A-\u105D\u1061\u1065\u1066\u106E-\u1070\u1075-\u1081\u108E\u10A0-\u10C5\u10C7\u10CD\u10D0-\u10FA\u10FC-\u1248\u124A-\u124D\u1250-\u1256\u1258\u125A-\u125D\u1260-\u1288\u128A-\u128D\u1290-\u12B0\u12B2-\u12B5\u12B8-\u12BE\u12C0\u12C2-\u12C5\u12C8-\u12D6\u12D8-\u1310\u1312-\u1315\u1318-\u135A\u1380-\u138F\u13A0-\u13F4\u1401-\u166C\u166F-\u167F\u1681-\u169A\u16A0-\u16EA\u1700-\u170C\u170E-\u1711\u1720-\u1731\u1740-\u1751\u1760-\u176C\u176E-\u1770\u1780-\u17B3\u17D7\u17DC\u1820-\u1877\u1880-\u18A8\u18AA\u18B0-\u18F5\u1900-\u191C\u1950-\u196D\u1970-\u1974\u1980-\u19AB\u19C1-\u19C7\u1A00-\u1A16\u1A20-\u1A54\u1AA7\u1B05-\u1B33\u1B45-\u1B4B\u1B83-\u1BA0\u1BAE\u1BAF\u1BBA-\u1BE5\u1C00-\u1C23\u1C4D-\u1C4F\u1C5A-\u1C7D\u1CE9-\u1CEC\u1CEE-\u1CF1\u1CF5\u1CF6\u1D00-\u1DBF\u1E00-\u1F15\u1F18-\u1F1D\u1F20-\u1F45\u1F48-\u1F4D\u1F50-\u1F57\u1F59\u1F5B\u1F5D\u1F5F-\u1F7D\u1F80-\u1FB4\u1FB6-\u1FBC\u1FBE\u1FC2-\u1FC4\u1FC6-\u1FCC\u1FD0-\u1FD3\u1FD6-\u1FDB\u1FE0-\u1FEC\u1FF2-\u1FF4\u1FF6-\u1FFC\u2071\u207F\u2090-\u209C\u2102\u2107\u210A-\u2113\u2115\u2119-\u211D\u2124\u2126\u2128\u212A-\u212D\u212F-\u2139\u213C-\u213F\u2145-\u2149\u214E\u2183\u2184\u2C00-\u2C2E\u2C30-\u2C5E\u2C60-\u2CE4\u2CEB-\u2CEE\u2CF2\u2CF3\u2D00-\u2D25\u2D27\u2D2D\u2D30-\u2D67\u2D6F\u2D80-\u2D96\u2DA0-\u2DA6\u2DA8-\u2DAE\u2DB0-\u2DB6\u2DB8-\u2DBE\u2DC0-\u2DC6\u2DC8-\u2DCE\u2DD0-\u2DD6\u2DD8-\u2DDE\u2E2F\u3005\u3006\u3031-\u3035\u303B\u303C\u3041-\u3096\u309D-\u309F\u30A1-\u30FA\u30FC-\u30FF\u3105-\u312D\u3131-\u318E\u31A0-\u31BA\u31F0-\u31FF\u3400-\u4DB5\u4E00-\u9FCC\uA000-\uA48C\uA4D0-\uA4FD\uA500-\uA60C\uA610-\uA61F\uA62A\uA62B\uA640-\uA66E\uA67F-\uA697\uA6A0-\uA6E5\uA717-\uA71F\uA722-\uA788\uA78B-\uA78E\uA790-\uA793\uA7A0-\uA7AA\uA7F8-\uA801\uA803-\uA805\uA807-\uA80A\uA80C-\uA822\uA840-\uA873\uA882-\uA8B3\uA8F2-\uA8F7\uA8FB\uA90A-\uA925\uA930-\uA946\uA960-\uA97C\uA984-\uA9B2\uA9CF\uAA00-\uAA28\uAA40-\uAA42\uAA44-\uAA4B\uAA60-\uAA76\uAA7A\uAA80-\uAAAF\uAAB1\uAAB5\uAAB6\uAAB9-\uAABD\uAAC0\uAAC2\uAADB-\uAADD\uAAE0-\uAAEA\uAAF2-\uAAF4\uAB01-\uAB06\uAB09-\uAB0E\uAB11-\uAB16\uAB20-\uAB26\uAB28-\uAB2E\uABC0-\uABE2\uAC00-\uD7A3\uD7B0-\uD7C6\uD7CB-\uD7FB\uF900-\uFA6D\uFA70-\uFAD9\uFB00-\uFB06\uFB13-\uFB17\uFB1D\uFB1F-\uFB28\uFB2A-\uFB36\uFB38-\uFB3C\uFB3E\uFB40\uFB41\uFB43\uFB44\uFB46-\uFBB1\uFBD3-\uFD3D\uFD50-\uFD8F\uFD92-\uFDC7\uFDF0-\uFDFB\uFE70-\uFE74\uFE76-\uFEFC\uFF21-\uFF3A\uFF41-\uFF5A\uFF66-\uFFBE\uFFC2-\uFFC7\uFFCA-\uFFCF\uFFD2-\uFFD7\uFFDA-\uFFDC .]*)(?=">)/g;

    quote_candidates.map(function(quote_candidate){
        quote_candidate_html = quote_candidate[0];
        author = re.exec(quote_candidate_html);
        if(!author){ //Debugging purposes: log all of the quote candidates that weren't matched by the regex
            console.log(author);
            console.log(quote_candidate_html);
        } else {
            authors.push(author);
        }
    });
}

//Get the blocks of HTML in the page that potentially have a quote within them. 
function get_quote_candidates(html_string){
    quote_candidates = [];
    var re = /<ul>\n<li>[\s\S]*?(?=<\/ul>\n<\/li>\n<\/ul>)/g;
    console.log(typeof(html_string));
    var next_quote_candidate;
    while(next_quote_candidate = re.exec(html_string)){
        quote_candidates.push(next_quote_candidate);
    }
    return quote_candidates;
}
```

**Examples of strings that aren't matched in the application, but are matched in the test tool**

```
<ul>
<li>Not with dreams, but with blood and with iron<br />
Shall a nation be moulded to last.
<ul>
<li><a href="/wiki/Algernon_Charles_Swinburne" title="Algernon Charles 
Swinburne">Algernon Charles Swinburne</a>, <i>A Word for the Country</i>.
</li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>


<ul>
<li>Man is the only animal that deals in that atrocity of atrocities, War. He is the only one that gathers his brethren about him and goes forth in cold blood and calm pulse to exterminate his kind. He is the only animal that for sordid wages will march out…and help to slaughter strangers of his own species who have done him no harm and with whom he has no quarrel … and in the intervals between campaigns he washes the blood off his hands and works for "the universal brotherhood of man" — with his mouth.
<ul>
<li><a href="/wiki/Mark_Twain" title="Mark Twain">Mark Twain</a>, <i>The War Prayer</i>.</li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Have you test your code against the missing "quotes". Maybe the problem is not in the JS code but in the regex itself that cannot find the match if, let's say, there are spaces of others uncounted characters...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have slept on it and discovered the problem/solution.

**TL;DR**

1. Remove the global flag from the regex pattern (I have no need for the global flag here, so I have opted to just remove it);  **or**
2. set the `lastIndex` property back to 0 before each search . i.e.

```
re.lastIndex = 0;
re.exec(your_string_to_search_goes_here);
```

**Explanation**

I had the global flag set but was applying the regex pattern iteratively to each element of an array. The regex object updates the `lastIndex` property when a match is found, provided the global flag is set. This is useful so that whatever pattern matching function you end up using knows where to start from after each time it matches something in your string.

For my use case, the global flag was totally unnecessary because I had already elementised the strings to search into an array, and I know that *if* there is to be a match, I expect there to be 1 and only 1, so remembering where the search pattern was last up to is irrelevant - if it doesn't match, move onto the next array element.

More useful threads here:

- [RegExp.exec() returns NULL sporadically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4724701/regexp-exec-returns-null-sporadically)
- [Regex.prototype.exec returns null on second iteration of the search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23298944/regex-prototype-exec-returns-null-on-second-iteration-of-the-search)