# How to write data to textarea from the for loop?

Tags: javascript

When adding a list of links to textarea, where each link is written in a separate line:

```
    google.com
    www.google.com
    ftp://ftp.google.com
    www.google.com
    www.google.com
    https://www.google.com/
    https://www.google.com.sg/
```

It is necessary to cut out everything except the domain, which the regular expression copes with https://regex101.com/r/x3IUMm/1.

```js
        const element = document.getElementById("bulkDomains");

        function parseUrls(e) {
            let domains = element.value.split('\n');
            const re = /(?:[\w-]+\..)+[\w-]+/g;

            element.value = "";

            for (let i = 0, ln = domains.length; i < ln; ++i) {
                element.value += re.exec(domains[i]) + '\n';
                re.exec(domains[i]);
            }

        }

        element.addEventListener('change', parseUrls);
```

```html
<textarea id="bulkDomains" name="domains[]">
google.com
www.google.com
ftp://ftp.google.com
www.google.com
www.google.com
https://www.google.com/
https://www.google.com.sg/
</textarea>
```

Only the last processed domain is inserted into textarea, the other domains are not inserted. How to insert processed domains back into textarea from the for loop?

Comment: What are you trying to do.  If you are trying to replace the text areas with only the hostname or append to the area with the matched URL.  Right now your code appends `domain[0]`, which is just a letter.  Maybe you wanted `domains[i]`.  Also, you have a global search issue (see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23298944/regex-prototype-exec-returns-null-on-second-iteration-of-the-search )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const element = document.getElementById("bulkDomains");

        function parseUrls(e) {
            let domains = element.value.split('\n');
            const re = /(?:[\w-]+\..)+[\w-]+/g;

            element.value = "";

            for (let i = 0, ln = domains.length; i < ln; ++i) {
                element.value += re.exec(domains[i]) + '\n';
                re.exec(domains[i]);
            }

        }

        element.addEventListener('change', parseUrls);
```

```html
<textarea id="bulkDomains" name="domains[]">
google.com
www.google.com
ftp://ftp.google.com
www.google.com
https://www.google.com/
https://www.google.com.sg/
</textarea>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).